# DATA WARE HOUSE Model with 1 to M and M*M relationship

Tags: database-design, data-warehouse, business-intelligence

I'am modeling a data warehouse. let me explain the situation :

- An Event has many Meeting
- An event has many Accounts
- An Event has a Debut date and an End date
- A meeting must be a part of an event
- A meeting has one or many Supervisor ( A supervisor can supervise many meetings )   - Many to Many
- A meeting has one or more issuers ( issuers can participate in many meetings ) - Many to Many
- A meeting has one or more investors ( investors can participate in many meetings ) - Many to Many

here is my Model :

[image]

I googled a bit and I found that there is what we call the bridge solution but I haven't well understood what is it for and if I have to use it in my model.

Thankx

Answer (score 0):

Bridge model can be called as the Snowflake schema in other words. This method is really helpful when it comes to handling many to many relationships as in your scenario. Using this model, you can break down dimension tables into sub dimension tables. Normally as we know, Dimension tables has unique rows. If we get an example for this from your scenario, Dim_meeting and dim_supervisor has rows which are unique from each other. That is, every row in supervisor is unique and no repeating data available. So to handle many to many relationships it is hard to do it without a bridge table between the two dimensions. for the same example I took (meeting and supervisor) a supervisor may supervise many meetings. and one meeting may have many supervisors according to you.

In this case, if we introduce a bridge table between the two, the bridge table will have its own unique id (surrogate key - primary key), supervisor ID and the meeting ID. Meeting dimension will have all unique meeting records and Supervisor Dimension will have unique supervisor records. The bridge table will have many records for a supervisor and many records for a meeting So that many to many relationships will be created in the bridge table.

That's how it works.

I also have handled many similar situations using bridge tables that seems to work really great when addressing similar issues.
Hope you get the idea

Comment: Thankx for your answer ! I already made a Model with Bridge Table but I have one more question : why to add a (surrogate key - primary key), in the bridge table as well as the two ID's ( ex : supervisor and meeting ) 
What I have done is to create a bridge table between each Dimension related by a Many to Many relationship but in the bridge Table I put only Two foreign keys that reference on both ID's !

Comment: yes, your design is fine, surrogate key is actually a unique number for each row. Normally in Dimension designs, we use a surrogate key in most cases. its like a key to uniquely identify a particular row. That's why I mentioned it. it acts as a row number, nothing much. Just  following the concepts :)

Comment: @S.BM for a different perspective, I typically don't add a separate surrogate to bridge tables - you can if you like and it may be helpful down the line, but it's not necessary and I'm not completely convinced that it's good practice as a generalization.

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative is to have a single EVENT_ACTIVITY fact where everything is represented as an "activity":

```
ACTIVITY_ID
PARENT_ACTIVITY_ID
ACTIVITY_LEVEL
ACTIVITY_TYPE
START_DATE
END_DATE
PERSON_ID
other DIM Keys
```

The types of activities would be Events, Meetings, Attendance, Supervision, anything else you may want to incljude.
For many-to-many meeting/supervisor you will have multiple Supervision Activity records with the same Parent Event.